# New Answer Notification Hard to Read

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

So the push of the redesign build happened about an hour ago, and I think some things are looking good so far. But I thought I'd point out that the notification about new answers that others have posted can be *really* hard to read...

> [image: New Answer Notification]

...especially when there is some text behind it.

> [image]

It was a lot more noticeable and better-looking when the orange bar came down from the top of the screen, at least to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been fixed on live. Please let me know if it's still bugging out for you.